# Ruby return method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there any difference between?

```
def some_method
  some_instructions and return
end
```

and:

```
def some_method
  return some_instructions
end
```

Comment: Both methods have code smell because, in Ruby, `return` is implied at the end of a method, and Ruby automatically returns the value of the last operation. So, in both, simply use `some_instructions` as the last line before you close the method and you'll accomplish what you want. `return` is used when you want to *force* Ruby to return a value somewhere before the end of the method; If `return` has a parameter it will be returned, otherwise it defaults to `nil`. `and return` is code-smell and discouraged. See "[Ruby Styleguide](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby)" for reasons why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is.

```
def some_method
  some_instructions and return
end
```

returns `nil`. **UPDATE:** As Arie Shaw pointed out and Jorg's answer is, if `some_instructions` is false (or nil), the method will return false (or nil) and will not run `return`

```
def some_method
  return some_instructions
end
```

returns the value returned by `some_instructions`

Comment: The first one may return `false` from `some_instructions`

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is: the first one returns `nil` if the return value of `some_instructions` is truthy and the return value of `some_instructions` if the return value of `some_instructions` is falsy. The second one always returns the return value of `some_instructions`.